# Using BeautifulSoup in a BeeWare app gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-import, python-venv, beeware

I am trying to import `beautifulsoup4`in a BeeWare app (with its own virtual environment) using the command:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

But I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'` even though I have installed `beautifulsoup4` in my virtual environment and added it to the dependencies in my `pyproject.toml` file. What's the issue then? Solutions I have found for regular virtual environments do not seem to apply to BeeWare apps. The issue only arises when I run the `briefcase run` command, but not with `briefcase dev`.

Comment: Does this [github issue](https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues/559#issuecomment-896369811) help you? They're having a similar issues as you, but with another module.

Comment: Maybe provide a [mre], in order to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @MarceloPaco I get the same errors even after following all those steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`briefcase dev` runs the app within your current environment, but `briefcase run` uses a separate environment containing only the requirements in your pyproject.toml file. Whenever you change that requirements list, you'll have to update the app's environment by adding the `-r` option to the `briefcase run` command.

For more details, see:

- The [`briefcase run`](https://briefcase.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/commands/run.html) documentation
- The [third-party libraries page](https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-7.html) of the BeeWare tutorial

Comment: I should have specified that I still get the error even when adding the -r option. So, unfortunately, that did not solve my issue.

Comment: Then please create an issue on the [Briefcase GitHub page](https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues), and make sure you include the log of `briefcase run -r`, and the relevant sections of your pyproject.toml file.

Comment: My bad, I had added the requirements under `test_sources` instead of `requires`. Marking your answer as correct because it helped me identify the issue!